# Which sentence should I say to change my shoes?

Tags: meaning

Let's say that  I bought a shose but after going home I realized that it is small for me . In this case which sentence would be better to tell this situation to staff in the shoe store?

> I need one size bigger shoes than this.
>
> I need one size bigger one of this model.
>
> I need this shoes in size one number bigger than this.

Answer (score 2):

Any of those would probably work.

Use of "model" is not idiomatic, and "size one number" is not correct. So the first sentence looks best.

But I don't think I'd use any phrase like this; I can ask directly for a size. So after greeting the shop worker and telling her that "the shoes are too small" (provide context) I'd ask:

> Do you have these in a size 8?

Notice, I'm phrasing as a question, rather than a combative "I need".  I'm also telling the worker what they actually need (the size)

Note "these" not "this" (since you normally buy a pair of shoes)